# How to remove multiple spaces in Strings with Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7, removing-whitespace

Until Swift 2 I used this extension to remove multiple whitespaces:

```
func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).filter({!Swift.isEmpty($0)})
        return " ".join(components)
}
```

but with Swift 2 now I get the error

> Cannot invoke 'isEmpty' with an argument list of type '(String)'

How could I now remove multiple spaces with Swift 2?
Thnx!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In **Swift 2**, `join` has become `joinWithSeparator` and you call it on the array.

In `filter`, `isEmpty` should be called on the current iteration item `$0`.

To replace whitespaces and newline characters with unique space characters as in your question:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let result = "Hello  World.\nHello!".condenseWhitespace()  // "Hello World. Hello!"
```

Because your function does not take any parameter you could make it a property instead:

```
extension String {
    var condensedWhitespace: String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let result = "Hello  World.\nHello!".condensedWhitespace  // "Hello World. Hello!"
```

---

In **Swift 3** there's even more changes.

Function:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let result = "Hello  World.\nHello!".condenseWhitespace()
```

Property:

```
extension String {
    var condensedWhitespace: String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let result = "Hello  World.\nHello!".condensedWhitespace
```

In **Swift 4.2** NSCharacterSet is now CharacterSet, and you can omit and use dot syntax:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let result = "Hello  World.\nHello!".condenseWhitespace()  // "Hello World. Hello!"
```

Comment: be careful, if you want to make it work with whitespacesAndNewlines you need to manage new lines as new lines and not " " when you join.
**
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
        let tmpstr = components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
        let components2 = tmpstr.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        return components2.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: "\n")
    }**

Comment: The extension works great in Swift 5. Lifesaving code! Thank you :)

Answer (score 32):

Splitting the string to an array and then joining again is not memory-efficient. It takes a lot of memory. The best way in this case is to scan the given string and perform operations on it using **regular expressions**. The solution is given below:

**Swift 4.x**

```swift
extension String {
    
    func removeExtraSpaces() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\s\n]+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let originalString = "Hello   world! \n\n I am   here!"
let processedString = originalString.removeExtraSpaces()
print(processedString)
```

Output:

```
"Hello world! I am here!"
```

You can do more according to your own requirements, but my point here is to use regular expressions rather than creating arrays which would consume lots of memory.

Comment: Thank you! This is better than creating unnecessary arrays.

Comment: @JeanNicolas For That, you can use .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) function by adding it to your extension. The Above solution is reducing more than 1 spaces or newlines to 1 space. I will really appreciate if you can make this functionality more responsible to trim the sting also.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 13):

**Cleanest version**. Documented, memory efficient, extremely easy to use.

```
extension String {

    /// Returns a condensed string, with no extra whitespaces and no new lines.
    var condensed: String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\s\n]+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }

    /// Returns a condensed string, with no whitespaces at all and no new lines.
    var extraCondensed: String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\s\n]+", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }

}
```

### Usage:

```
let a = " Hello\n  I am  a string  ".condensed
let b = " Hello\n  I am  a string  ".extraCondensed
```

### Output:

a: "Hello I am a string"

b: "HelloIamastring"

Answer (score 8):

SWIFT 3: Cleaner version

```
extension String {
    var condensedWhitespace: String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: What the advantage of using var over func?

Comment: I don't think it's making any difference. Just saving you ()

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine: How it's actually worked.

```
extension String {

    func removeExtraSpaces() -> String {
        var data  = ""
        var numberOfSpace = 0
        let items = self.getComponents(separatedBy: " ")
        for item in items{
            if item == " "{
                numberOfSpace = numberOfSpace + 1
            }else{
                numberOfSpace = 0
            }
            if numberOfSpace == 1 || numberOfSpace == 0 {
                data =  data + item
                //data.append(item)
            }
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

**Usages**

```
 var message = "What  is the    purpose   of life?"
 message = message.removeExtraSpaces()
 print(message)
```

**Output:**

> What is the purpose of life?

Answer (score 1):

Code below work for me. I needed to remove EXTRA spaces from string.

```
var example = "    Hello       world   "

func removeSpacers(from word: String) -> String {
var finalResult = ""
var spacesCount = 0

let trimmed = word.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
let components = trimmed.components(separatedBy: " ")

// if we have not any spaces we returning trimmed string
guard components.contains(where: { $0 == "" }) else { return trimmed }
components.forEach {
    // because .components returning ""(empty string)
    if $0 == "" {
        spacesCount += 1
    } else {
        // if another element not space, we could add space(the space between words)
        if spacesCount != 0 {
            spacesCount = 0
            finalResult.append(" ")
        }
    }
    // so if we have no spaces we could add word no result string
    if spacesCount == 0 {
        finalResult.append($0)
    }
}
return finalResult
```

}

I make a couple of tests, its work.

```
 func testRemoveSpaceFromStringWithSpacesOnCenter() {
    // given
    let string = "Hello     world"

    // when
    let result = pfromatter.removeSpaces(from: string)

    // then
    let expected = "Hello world"
    XCTAssertEqual(expected, result)
}

func testRemoveSpaceFromStringWithSpacesOnSide() {
    // given
    let string = " Hello world "

    // when
    let result = pfromatter.removeSpaces(from: string)

    // then
    let expected = "Hello world"
    XCTAssertEqual(expected, result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Hello  World.\nHello!"

if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s+", options:NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
{
    str = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count), withTemplate: " ")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **duplicate** whitespace and any **leading/trailing** whitespace in one go, you can use the below solution:

```swift
extension String {
    func trimmingExtraWhitespace() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?<=\\s)\\s+|\\s+(?=$)|(?<=^)\\s+", 
                                         with: "", 
                                         options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```

What it does:

- `(?<=\\s)\\s+` matches all whitespace preceded by a space
- `\\s+(?=$)` matches all whitespace at the end of a string
- `(?<=^)\\s+` matches all whitespace at the beginning of a string

Remarks:

- `\s` in regex includes spaces, tabs and line breaks, so you don't need to explicitly specify `\n`.
- You need to escape `\s` in Swift, thus the double backward slash `\\`

Example:

```swift
var originalString = "  Hello   world  "
var processedString = originalString.trimmingExtraWhitespace()
print("Original: \(originalString)")
print("Processed: \(processedString)")
```

Output:

```
Original:   Hello   world  
Processed: Hello world
```