# Remove whitespaces from a string

Tags: swift

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940044/how-to-remove-all-the-spaces-and-n-r-in-a-string/34940183) SO post to remove whitespaces and newline characters from a string. But in my string, I may have extra whitespaces as well as extra newline characters. I want to remove the unnecessary \n's and whitespaces from that string.

But if there is a string like so...`"This \n is a st\tri\rng"` then I don't want `Thisisastring` as the result but instead something like this..

`This is a string`

Comment: There is no well defined logic here. Hence you cannot code for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058676/how-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-strings-with-swift-2.

Comment: Would suggest you regex format to determine extra spacing between words and remove them.

Comment: Try `string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`

Comment: @Kamran That only removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Its easy to replace contiguous whitespaces with one whitespace, by regular expression or split-join. However, that `st\tri\rng` thing is completely not predictable. How can you differentiate whitespaces within a word and between words?

Comment: let newStr = urSTring.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all the spaces and \n\r in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940044/how-to-remove-all-the-spaces-and-n-r-in-a-string)

Comment: Unless you provide rules to differentiate spaces within a word and spaces betweens words, it is not possible.

Comment: Ok...so if my string is `This   \n\n is a string` i.e. having just extra newline characters and whitespaces, then how can I get a something like `This is a string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace contiguous spaces with a single space, replace Regular Expression `\s+` with a single space:

```
let str = "This \n\n is a string"
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s+", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
{
    let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count), withTemplate: " ")
    print(result)  //output: "This is a string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricky Mo...But there's one more concern..if I have a text one below the other, then with the above code, I'll finally get it one after the other as it deletes the newlines. What has to be done if I want the text to appear one below the other itself but without the `\n` being shown..?

Comment: By `This \n\n is a string` -> `This is a string`, you just meant you want to remove the newlines. If you want to preserve some newlines, what is your rule to determine which newlines to be preserved and which to be removed?